# Launching Ubuntu desktop GUI on ubuntiu server on Docker

Tags: launcher, docker

I am new to docker and have set up an ubuntu server on a docker image pulled from docker hub.
I went ahead and installed following these steps:

1. Log into the server.
2. Type the command

   ```
   sudo apt-get update
   ```

   to update the list of software packages available.
3. Type the command

   ```
   sudo apt-get install ubuntu-desktop
   ```

   to install the Gnome desktop.
4. Type the command

   ```
   sudo apt-get install xubuntu-desktop
   ```

   to install the XFCE desktop.
5. Type the command

   ```
   sudo apt-get install kubuntu-desktop
   ```

   to install the KDE desktop.
6. Type the command

   ```
   sudo reboot
   ```

   to reboot the server.

---

But I cannot reboot per last step above, as it's a docker image.

So my question is: **how do I launch the Ubuntu desktop GUI?**